# Searching for year in a date field with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

How can I search for a specific (date of birth) year in a date field with Ransack?

Currently the code looks like this:

*Controller*

```
def index
    @search = Athlete.search(params[:q])  
    @athletes = @search.result
end
```

*View*

```
<%= f.label :birthdate_cont, "Birth Date" %>
<%= f.text_field :birthdate_cont, class: "form-control" %>
```

The above does not seem to do any filtering, most likely because I am comparing a string to a date?

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting the date in params? Is it a simple one box to enter date string? Is it divided as in a drop down?

Comment: The first. A simple text box for the year...

Answer (score 2):

For ransack you need to use Arel in your model to handle conversion of string and Datetime:

```
ransacker :birthdate_cont do
  Arel.sql('date(birthdate_cont)')
end
```

Also, I feel two fields which allow selection between two dates (start and end) would be a better option.

Read more here: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers#2-convert-a-user-string-input-and-a-database-datetime-field-to-the-same-date-format-to-find-all-records-with-a-datetime-field-created_at-in-this-example-equal-to-that-date-

---

Now, outside Ransack (If writing your own search method), if the search is a class method in your Athlete class:

Firstly, if it's a text field, you need to specify the format. You can use `DateTime.parse` and play around with it.

Secondly, for a search, you can take that output and create a new DateTime object as in :

```
User.where(:birthdate => Datetime.new(2018, 01, 10, 22, 37, 2 ))
```

But I feel your query should search for any DateTime which lies between 00:00:00  and 23:59:59 on that particular date **if you are using DateTime and not Date as an entity type (This would be a great place to think if you are using the best entity type for your database as well)**. So the query could be like;

`User.where(:birthdate => Datetime.new(2018, 01, 09, 0, 0, 0)..Datetime.new(2018, 01, 10, 23, 59, 59 ))` in your search class method. For this to work I am assuming search is a class method which you can alter depending upon the params.

Comment: It still does not apply any filtering to the records. The only way I can make it work is to enter the whole date (e.g., 2010-12-06) in the text box. However, when I enter just the year (e.g., 2010) it displays all the records.....

Comment: Either you will need to create your own prefilter method which gives two DateTime objects: start and end. You will have to use logic to return the start and enddates depending upon what's present. If only YYYY is present it should give you range YY,01,01 as start and YY,12,31 as end.

Or use a drop-down. Why not try using a drop-down where people can choose all the date in the range min - max with YY, MM, DD in separate columns. That would be eaiser.

Comment: I will also suggest waiting for other users to comment (who are more experienced using Ransack). I normally write my own search method rather than use an external dependency for complex searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datetime column and a date input like `dd/mm/yyyy` you can use this ransacker:

```
# your_model.rb
ransacker :created_on, formatter: proc { |value| Date.parse(value).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') } do
  Arel.sql("DATE(#{table_name}.created_at)")
end
```

Given the input date `01/10/2018`, it will search like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(table.created_at) = '2018-10-01'
```